# Why do electric companies measure in watts, when they be measuring in joules?

Tags: measurement, watts

1 Joule is defined as `1 Watt of power working for 1 second`.

When the electric bill comes, it says "you've used 5000 Watts, therefore pay us $100".

However, from what I understand, if I turn on a 5000 Watt oven for even three seconds, you can say I used 5000 watts. However, for the purpose of measuring how much energy I used, wouldn't it be more correct to say I used 1500 Joules?

Why then does the electric company measure in watts when really they are charging you based on a combination of the power used and the amount of time you used it for?

Comment: Don't they say KiloWattHour? The KWh is a unit of energy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, the electric bill does NOT say *"you have used 5000 Watts".*  Look at it more closely.  It says that you used *5000 kiloWatt-hours*.  A kilowatt-hour is one kiloWatt (1000 Watts) for one hour.  That is a measure of energy, and is the same as charging for Joules.  One kiloWatt-hour **equals** 3.6 MJoules.  Or put another way, they do charge by the Joule, just that they express it in more relevant units for most homeowners.

Answer (score 6):

1 KiloWatt-Hour (kWh) is \$3.6 \times 10^6\$ Joules. All my electricity bills give usage in kWh.

Just be thankful if they don't charge by [British Thermal Units (BTU)](http://www.aps.org/policy/reports/popa-reports/energy/units.cfm), [Ergs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erg) or [Electron Volts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt)

Comment: I'd so love to find something about 10³⁰ eV in my bill...

Comment: BTU? Good 'ole 'merican unit, the Ton, would be more useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton_of_refrigeration